# Flux of diffeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, symplectic-geometry

I try to solve the problem that find the Flux of diffeomorphism $T^2 \to T^2$ , $(\theta_1,\theta_2) \to (\theta_1+1/2,\theta_2+1/3)$, $\theta_i \in S^1$ in terms of the isomorphism $H^1(T^2;R)=R^2$

Comment: Would you mind to give some details on why you tried?

Comment: Actually, I have  no idea that what is the Flux of diffeomorphism. Could you give some hint?

Comment: To know what the question is about is certainly a prerequisite to solving it! In what context exactly did you came across this question? The definition of the flux morphism of an *isotopy* of symplectic diffeomorphisms is given in *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* by McDuff & Salamon and also in *The Geometry of the Group of Symplectic Diffeomorphisms* by Polterovich.

Comment: Thanks for answer. After your comment, i saw a hint in the course notes. It is written that $Flux (id) \in Z^2 \subset R^2=H^1(T^2)$ and $Flux(f)=R^2 / Z^2 =T^2$. Consider the integrals and periods. After  Flux you will get same points.